# Is it possible to put the reader.result in const audio = new Audio("");, namely in ""? If so, please tell me how to do it

Tags: javascript

Tell me, please, is it possible to put the ***reader.result*** in ***const audio = new Audio("");***, namely in **""**? If so, please tell me how to do it.
Full code:

```
function previewWAV() {
var preview = document.querySelector('.download-button.fas.fa-download');
var previewDisplay = document.querySelector('.preview-div.wav');
var file    = document.querySelector('#upload').files[0];
var reader  = new FileReader();

previewDisplay.style.display = "block";

reader.onloadend = function () { preview.href = reader.result; const audio = new Audio("reader.result"); }

if (file) { reader.readAsDataURL(file); } else { preview.src = ""; } }
```

Comment: If you specifically want it inside a string try this: `const audio = new Audio(\`${reader.result}\`);`

Answer (score 0):

That won't work.

`Audio()` [accepts a URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio) as its sole parameter.

`FileReader.result` returns [the contents of the file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result), not its URL.

If the file you're trying to play is already at a URL you can just feed that URL to `Audio()` and skip the whole FileReader step.

If you're trying to preview a file before upload, you can use `URL.createObjectURL()` on the file object to [generate a usable DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) you can pass to `Audio()`:

```
let file = document.querySelector('#upload').files[0];
let fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
let audio = new Audio(fileURL);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please tell me how to put in a DOMString the URL that is in reader.result and then pass it to Audio()?